# Spotify not receiving remapped XF86Audio signals

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, thinkpad, xmodmap

I have a external USB Thinkpad keyboard I'm using with my Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 16. I'm trying to remap my `Fn`+`F7`, `Fn`+`F8`, and `Fn`+`F9` keys to send the `XF86AudioPrev`, `XF86AudioPlay`, and `XF86AudioNext` signals to control what I'm listening to on Spotify.

Using `xev` I've determined that the keycodes of the keys are `235`, `246`, and `179`, respectively and I'm using the following commands in my `.Xmodmap` to change the "behavior"of the keys.

```
keycode 235 = XF86AudioPrev
keycode 246 = XF86AudioPlay
keycode 179 = XF86AudioNext
```

Testing with `xev` after, I get the following output, with the correct output for each key.

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3200001,
    root 0x4cb, subw 0x0, time 11067891, (1436,551), root:(1436,606),
    state 0x0, keycode 246 (keysym 0x1008ff14, XF86AudioPlay), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 172
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

However, while listening to music, Spotify doesn't recognize any of the signals. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or if I have to do anything else?